# Retornar Código do objeto assim que inserido

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Preciso fazer um insert no Entity Framework e ao mesmo tempo retorna o código do objeto inserido,
evitando assim um novo acesso ao banco.

Comment: Oi, Marconi, confira minha edição para tentar não repetir os mesmos erros. Quanto mais detalhes você colocar na própria pergunta, mais rápido/fácil vai ser obter uma resposta. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Entendi que você quer o retorno do Id de um objeto, se a coluna Id é inteira e `IDENTITY`.

Considerando que o mapeamento foi feito dentro das normativas do Entity Framework:

```
[DisplayColumn("Nome")]
public class Fruta
{
    [Key]
    public int FrutaId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Basta inserir e ler o Id do objeto:

```
var fruta = new Fruta { Nome = "Laranja" };
context.Frutas.Add(fruta);
context.SaveChanges();

var idDaFruta = fruta.FrutaId;
```

Comment: Cigano muito obrigado. Eu não sabia que após salvar o objeto eu já teria o código dele disponível. Agradeço pela resposta.